# Vi mode in other console programs

Tags: terminal, vi

I quite like the Vi mode of bash. Is there any way to make it work in other programs (gnuplot for instance)?

**EDIT:** As Shawn suggested below, configuring `.inputrc` and using `rlwrap -a -c gnuplot` gives Vi mode for gnuplot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this mode in any program that uses the readline library by adding [`set editing-mode vi`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX15) to [`~/.inputrc`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9).

You can also use [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) to make other programs use readline.

Comment: Also works with bash.  This is my default editing mode in bash.

Answer (score 1):

[Vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator) is a good plugin for Firefox.  The Chrome equivalent is called [vrome](http://www.chromeextensions.org/other/vrome/).

Comment: Also worth checking out: Pentadactyl (Firefox) and Vimium (Chrome).